# after each action, the program writes "not responding"

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

[image]I make a winter forest, but after adding particles to the trees, after each action the program does not want to work.
Then you need to wait five minutes after each action until it loads!
Help me please! I can’t work like that.
MY PC:
i5-9600k,
HyperX fury 2666mhz 8x2,
Gtx 1660 super,
Nvidia studio driver 451.48.

Comment: How big is your scene? How many trees, with how many particles? Things like full forests can be performance-heavy for programs like blender because of the way they need to keep everything stored in active memory and have to basically re-draw the entire scene every time there is a change. Try reducing your particle count, or hiding some objects you're not working on.

Comment: there are 2000 particles on each tree! the scale stands on all axes 30,000. I tried to turn off the rest of the trees, but still he thinks for a long time

Comment: The last thing I can think to try is to save your project, close blender, and open it again. This will wipe any orphaned data related to the scene which could be using resources. Other than that, it's hard to tell. Unfortunately, sometimes complex scenes are just slow to process. I get that when making complex shader node graphs. Every time I change something, I have to wait a while.

Comment: just after each action, even if it's just moving an object, I have to wait 5 minutes! it slows down too much :(

Comment: Yeah, there could be many factors at play. Occasionally I get a file that performs poorly like that. A last-ditch thing you can try is to select everything and copy it (ctrl+c), then open a new file and paste everything there. Sometimes the old project file was just corrupted for some reason, and pasting everything into a new project speeds it back up. It doesn't always work though. Sometimes you just have to keep playing with your scene, reducing geometry as necessary and making other performance tweaks until it becomes usable again.